# How to fill logic gates in circuitikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf, color, circuitikz

How can you specify a `fill` color for logic gates in `circuitikz`? It does not work as I would have expected:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz} \draw
(0,2) node[or port, fill=red] (myor) {}

(myor.in 1) node[left =.2cm] (a) {A}
(myor.in 2) node[left =.2cm] (b) {B}
(myor.out)  node[right=.2cm] (c) {C}

(myor.in 1) -- (a)
(myor.in 2) -- (b)
(myor.out)  -- (c);
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

The output still shows a transparent gate instead of a red one:

[image: transparent gate]

Comment: You should write a feature request to the maintainer of this package. As this would need redefinition of all the ports, it is maybe better do ask the author for such thing.

Comment: The short answer is "no."  Have you tried mixing tikz circuit components with circuitikz?  I've never had a problem (except for the default size difference).

Comment: @JohnKormylo I'll have a look at the `shapes.gates.logic.US` library, although the gates don't look as nice as the ones from `circuitikz`, in my opinion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `pgfcirctripoles.sty` defines the path of the shape and then draws it independently of your options, instead of just declaring the path and not using it.

If you modify the definition of the `or` ports in line 498 of `pgfcirctripoles.sty` as follows:

```
\pgfcircdeclarelogicport{or}{


    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint
        {\pgf@circ@res@left}
        {\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/circuitikz/tripoles/american or port/input height}\pgf@circ@res@up}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint
        {(\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/circuitikz/tripoles/american or port/port width}-\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/circuitikz/tripoles/american or port/input skip})*\pgf@circ@res@left}
        {\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/circuitikz/tripoles/american or port/input height}\pgf@circ@res@up}}

    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint
        {\pgf@circ@res@left}
        {\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/circuitikz/tripoles/american or port/input height}\pgf@circ@res@down}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint
        {(\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/circuitikz/tripoles/american or port/port width}-\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/circuitikz/tripoles/american or port/input skip})*\pgf@circ@res@left}
        {\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/circuitikz/tripoles/american or port/input height}\pgf@circ@res@down}}

    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@circ@res@right}{0pt}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint
        {\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/circuitikz/tripoles/american or port/port width}\pgf@circ@res@right}
        {0pt}}  

    %\pgfusepath{draw}
    \pgf@circ@res@other=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/circuitikz/tripoles/american or port/port width}\pgf@circ@res@right
    %\pgfsetlinewidth{2\pgflinewidth}
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{-\pgf@circ@res@other}{\pgf@circ@res@up}}
    \pgfpathcurveto
        {\pgfpoint{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/circuitikz/tripoles/american or port/aaa}\pgf@circ@res@left}{\pgf@circ@res@up}}
        {\pgfpoint{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/circuitikz/tripoles/american or port/bbb}\pgf@circ@res@left}{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/circuitikz/tripoles/american or port/ccc}\pgf@circ@res@up}}
        {\pgfpoint{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/circuitikz/tripoles/american or port/bbb}\pgf@circ@res@left}{0pt}}
    \pgfpathcurveto
        {\pgfpoint{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/circuitikz/tripoles/american or port/bbb}\pgf@circ@res@left}{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/circuitikz/tripoles/american or port/ccc}\pgf@circ@res@down}}
        {\pgfpoint{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/circuitikz/tripoles/american or port/aaa}\pgf@circ@res@left}{\pgf@circ@res@down}}
        {\pgfpoint{-\pgf@circ@res@other}{\pgf@circ@res@down}}   

    \pgfpathcurveto
        {\pgfpoint{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/circuitikz/tripoles/american or port/ddd}\pgf@circ@res@left}{\pgf@circ@res@down}}
        {\pgfpoint{\pgf@circ@res@other}{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/circuitikz/tripoles/american or port/ccc}\pgf@circ@res@down}}
        {\pgfpoint{\pgf@circ@res@other}{0pt}}
    \pgfpathcurveto
        {\pgfpoint{\pgf@circ@res@other}{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/circuitikz/tripoles/american or port/ccc}\pgf@circ@res@up}}
        {\pgfpoint{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/circuitikz/tripoles/american or port/ddd}\pgf@circ@res@left}{\pgf@circ@res@up}}
        {\pgfpoint{-\pgf@circ@res@other}{\pgf@circ@res@up}} 
    %\pgfusepath{draw}
}
```

(which is exactly as before minus few commented lines)
you obtain that:

1. the shape obeys the fill style
2. you need to put an explicit `draw` style in the node of the port (i.e. `(0,2) node[or port,fill=red,draw] (myor) {}`)

Comment: With this modification you will not be able to use it in the to-style form.

Comment: @JohnKormylo How would you use the to-style form with tripoles? The manual always uses nodes with these, which makes sense since you need to refer to their anchors to connect them to the rest of the circuit...

Comment: Some tripoles (such as transistors) can be treated like bipoles with an extra pin.  But you are right, or gates are not like that.  Never mind.

Comment: Personaly, I would have created a new component replacing draw with fill, and named it "or art".

Comment: Sure that would be nice but would require a lot more code as you would need to define all the related styles...I'm just giving a hint here as to where the problem lays (I'm not circuitikz expert!)

Comment: anyway being able to customize both draw and fill styles from keys in the node's style would be much nicer than having separate shapes for each use. But this requires a bigger reorganization of the library's code...

Comment: @JohnKormylo Sorry to come back to such a somehow old topic, though I am currently interested in having filled logic gates. You mentioned you would create a new component with a new name and by replacing draw with fill. Would you mind giving an example of the code needed ? Thanks in advance !

Comment: @Sergio - Basically it is the same process.  \pgfcircdeclarelogicport{or art} would create a new logic port, but you would need to create some additional pgfkeys (such as .../american or art port/height) and pre-define the fill color.