# How to color only part of a circuitikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf, circuitikz

I want to color part of my circuit but it seems that TeXstudio gets stuck every time.

My original code is:

```
% Power electronics---converters and inverter
% Author: Ali Mehrizi-Sani
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[american,cuteinductors,smartlabels]{circuitikz}

\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\ctikzset{bipoles/thickness=1}
\ctikzset{bipoles/length=0.8cm}
\ctikzset{bipoles/diode/height=.375}
\ctikzset{bipoles/diode/width=.3}
\ctikzset{tripoles/thyristor/height=.8}
\ctikzset{tripoles/thyristor/width=1}
\ctikzset{bipoles/vsourceam/height/.initial=.7}
\ctikzset{bipoles/vsourceam/width/.initial=.7}
\tikzstyle{every node}=[font=\small]
\tikzstyle{every path}=[line width=0.8pt,line cap=round,line join=round]

\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}
    \draw
    (0,0)
    to[V=$V_{in}$, invert] ++(0,2)
    to[short] ++(0.5,0)
    to[short] ++(0.7,0) coordinate(N1)
    to[L] ++(0,-2)
    to[short] (1.2,-.5)
    to[short] (0,-.5)
    to[short] (0,0)

    % ------------------------ Secondary side
    (N1)++(0.7,0) coordinate (N2)

    to[D*] ++(2.5,0) coordinate (C2pos)
    to[C, l_=$C$] ++(0,-2)
    (C2pos)
    to[short] ++(1.5,0)
    to[R, l_=$R$] ++(0,-2)
    to[short] ($(N2)+(0,-2)$)
    to[L] (N2)
    (C2pos)++(2,0)
    to[open, v^>=$v_{out}$] ++(0,-2)
    % ------------------------ Transformer lines
    ($(N1)!0.5!(N2)$)++(-0.05,-0.5)
    -- ++(0,-1) ++(0.1,0) -- ++(0,1)
    ($(N1)+(-0.15,-0.7)$) node[circ] {}
    ($(N2)+(+0.15,-1.3)$) node[circ] {}
    ;
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

Which produce successfully my circuit but I can't color only the primary side of the circuit

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to TeX.SE! The issue is that you draw the thing in a single path, and then it is next-to-impossible to change the color. But there is absolutely no need to draw it in a single path. Rather you could do

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[american,cuteinductors,smartlabels]{circuitikz}

\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\ctikzset{bipoles/thickness=1}
\ctikzset{bipoles/length=0.8cm}
\ctikzset{bipoles/diode/height=.375}
\ctikzset{bipoles/diode/width=.3}
\ctikzset{tripoles/thyristor/height=.8}
\ctikzset{tripoles/thyristor/width=1}
\ctikzset{bipoles/vsourceam/height/.initial=.7}
\ctikzset{bipoles/vsourceam/width/.initial=.7}
\tikzstyle{every node}=[font=\small]
\tikzstyle{every path}=[line width=0.8pt,line cap=round,line join=round]

\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}
    \draw[red]
    (0,0)
    to[V=$V_{in}$, invert] ++(0,2)
    to[short] ++(0.5,0)
    to[short] ++(0.7,0) coordinate(N1)
    to[L] ++(0,-2)
    to[short] (1.2,-.5)
    to[short] (0,-.5)
    to[short] (0,0);
    % ------------------------ Secondary side
    \draw (N1)++(0.7,0) coordinate (N2)

    to[D*] ++(2.5,0) coordinate (C2pos)
    to[C, l_=$C$] ++(0,-2)
    (C2pos)
    to[short] ++(1.5,0)
    to[R, l_=$R$] ++(0,-2)
    to[short] ($(N2)+(0,-2)$)
    to[L] (N2)
    (C2pos)++(2,0)
    to[open, v^>=$v_{out}$] ++(0,-2);
    % ------------------------ Transformer lines
    \draw($(N1)!0.5!(N2)$)++(-0.05,-0.5)
    -- ++(0,-1) ++(0.1,0) -- ++(0,1)
    ($(N1)+(-0.15,-0.7)$) node[circ] {}
    ($(N2)+(+0.15,-1.3)$) node[circ] {}
    ;
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Note that I will be offline for while, so please don't get mad at me if I do not respond immediately to comments. (The above is just an example, and I made no effort in coloring the left circle and so on, but it is certainly possible to do that in the same way.)

Answer (score 0):

One of the fundamental problems of these kind of things is that `tikzcircuit` [explicitly draw the path](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/188279/how-to-fill-logic-gates-in-circuitikz) (instead of preparing it), so `draw` parameters does not percolate correctly often in circuit components. In this case I would add to [Marmot's solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/458820/38080) the following (copying just the circuit, the rest is the same):

```
\begin{circuitikz}
    % color=red colors the components, just "red" only the wires
    % the  every node/.style is needed for the text in symbols
    \begin{scope}[color=red, every node/.style={color=red}]
      \draw[]
      (0,0)
      to[V=$V_{in}$, invert,] ++(0,2)
      to[short] ++(0.5,0)
      to[short] ++(0.7,0) coordinate(N1)
      to[L] ++(0,-2)
      to[short] (1.2,-.5)
      to[short] (0,-.5)
      to[short] (0,0);
    \end{scope}
    % ------------------------ Secondary side
    \draw (N1)++(0.7,0) coordinate (N2)

    to[D*] ++(2.5,0) coordinate (C2pos)
    to[C, l_=$C$] ++(0,-2)
    (C2pos)
    to[short] ++(1.5,0)
    to[R, l_=$R$] ++(0,-2)
    to[short] ($(N2)+(0,-2)$)
    to[L] (N2)
    (C2pos)++(2,0)
    to[open, v^>=$v_{out}$] ++(0,-2);
    % ------------------------ Transformer lines
    \draw($(N1)!0.5!(N2)$)++(-0.05,-0.5)
    -- ++(0,-1) ++(0.1,0) -- ++(0,1)
    % again, here "red" alone fails 
    ($(N1)+(-0.15,-0.7)$) node[color=red, circ] {}
    ($(N2)+(+0.15,-1.3)$) node[circ] {}
    ;
\end{circuitikz}
```

[image: output]